# Cannot open an encrypted Realm with a debugger attached to the process Error

Tags: ios, swift, realm

How can I prevent this error from crashing my app, while still keeping my realms encrypted?

I noticed that the example projects provided by Realm work fine, why does mine throw this exception?

> Cannot open an encrypted Realm with a debugger attached to the
>   process***  Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException',
>   reason: 'Cannot open an encrypted Realm with a debugger attached to
>   the process'

It states in the instructions that I must set "**REALM_DISABLE_ENCRYPTION=YES**", but where do I do this? Is there a way around this so that I can still debug the encrypted version? Do I set the value to =NO when uploading to the app store?

Comment: Edit your scheme (command+shift+<), select `Run`, select `Arguments` and add it to `Environment Variables`. And, no... this affects only the debug run.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing alot of that up, I get `open() failed: Permission denied
Unable to open a realm at path 'CustomRealm'. Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions.` when setting a custom realm, do you know if that is supported?

Comment: At that point, it's asking for the full file path to your realm file; right now, that's pointing straight at the root directory of your device. ;) If you're setting a custom realm file, make sure you get the system file path to your app's Documents directory and then append the name of the realm file to the end of that.